# Solving $x_{n+1}-n x_{n}=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

I think my TA messed up in this one. He used the thm. below to solve it.

[image]

He got $x_{n+1}-n x_{n}=\left(E^{1}-n E^{0}\right) x=\lambda-n=0 \Rightarrow \lambda=n$, and the solution (following from the theorem) $x(n)=\left[n, n^{2}, n^{3}, \cdots\right]$.

This is wrong because all the coefficient are not constant!

Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$X_{n+1}=n X_{n} ,$$let us do multiplicative telescopig:
$$X_2=1.X_1$$
$$X_3=2.X_2$$
$$X_4=3.X_3$$
$$X_5=4.X_4$$
$$.........$$
$$.........$$
$$X_{n-1}=(n-2)X_{n-2}$$
$$X_n=(n-1). X_{n-1}$$
Multiplying these equations, we get
$$X_n=1.2.3.4...(n-1)X_1 \implies X_n=(n-1)!~ X_0$$